# MySQL - Unable to use indexes in HEAP (MEMORY) tables for group by

Tags: mysql, optimization

In normal MyISAM tables (and probably InnoDB too) you can add indexes to increase the performance of queries using the GROUP BY statement, following the rules outlined here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-optimization.html

I've been doing some performance testing recently, trying out MySQL's ability to store tables directly in the memory (a.k.a. HEAP tables). I noticed something odd - group by queries are running far slower in heap tables than in MyISAM. Upon further investigation I observed that "Using index for group-by" doesn't show when EXPLAINing the heap table queries (they do in MyISAM).

I've been trying to find more information about this on the interent but to no avail. Is it not possible to use indexes for group by in HEAP tables?

Simple example:

```
-- Setting everything up

SET max_heap_table_size = 104857600;

CREATE TABLE lookup_mem
    (id INT, INDEX USING BTREE (id))
    ENGINE = MEMORY;

CREATE TABLE lookup_hdd
    (id INT, INDEX USING BTREE (id))
    ENGINE = MYISAM;


DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `populate_table`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE count INT DEFAULT 0;
    WHILE count < 3000000 DO
        INSERT INTO lookup_mem SET id = ROUND(RAND()*100);
        SET count = count + 1;
    END WHILE;
END$$

DELIMITER ;



CALL populate_table;

INSERT INTO lookup_hdd SELECT * FROM lookup_mem;
```

Now to the fun stuff:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM lookup_mem GROUP BY id;

-- gives
-- 1, SIMPLE, lookup_mem, index, , id, 5, , 3000000, 

EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM lookup_hdd GROUP BY id;

-- gives
-- 1, SIMPLE, lookup_hdd, range, , id, 5, , 101, Using index for group-by





SELECT * FROM lookup_mem GROUP BY id;

-- takes 1.216 seconds

SELECT * FROM lookup_hdd GROUP BY id;

-- takes 0.001 seconds
```

Does mysql not use indexes for group bys in heap tables?

Comment: yes, they [can and do](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html). how did you do your "identical" copy?

Comment: I exported the table sql, and changed engine. I've also tried making new super simple tables on two different servers using different configurations, but the btree indices of the HEAP tables get cardinality none and the index group by isn't showing in explain.

Comment: I tried copy pasting the create table query in that page you linked, but it behaves the same way.

Comment: Perhaps these indexes are version specific (e.g. your MySQL server is too old?)

Comment: I'm using 5.5.29. Please see the code example I added above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now a verified bug. See link:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68086